# inter vlan routing-dhcp offer reaches until newly created vlan ip but not my machine connected to the vlan

Tags: routing, vlan, hp-procurve

Default VLAN: `10..0.0/24` New VLAN : `10..8.0/24` DHCP server : `10.*.0.17`

I can see the DHCP offer packets making it back to my VLAN IP address namely 10.*.8.31 (from DHCP server message log)

```
Apr 28 15:33:13 dhcpd: DHCPOFFER on 10..8.129 to via 10..8.31
```

However, the DHCP offer never makes it back to my machine connected to the new VLAN (verified with Wireshark as well).

The switch is HP Layer-3 ProCurve.

Running-Config (some details redacted):

```
Running configuration:
*; J9588A Configuration Editor; Created on release #KA.15.17.0008
*module 1 type j9588y
module 2 type j9588x
-fault-finder broadcast-storm sensitivity high
fault-finder bad-driver sensitivity high
fault-finder bad-transceiver sensitivity high
fault-finder bad-cable sensitivity high
fault-finder too-long-cable sensitivity high
fault-finder over-bandwidth sensitivity high
fault-finder loss-of-link sensitivity high
fault-finder duplex-mismatch-hdx sensitivity high
fault-finder duplex-mismatch-fdx sensitivity high
fault-finder link-flap sensitivity high
jumbo ip-mtu 9000
power-over-ethernet redundancy n+1
qos tcp-port ipv4 22 priority 7
qos tcp-port ipv4 80 priority 1
qos tcp-port ipv4 443 priority 0
qos type-of-service diff-services
timesync sntp
sntp broadcast
sntp server priority 1 10.x.x.x
sntp server priority 2 10.x.x.x
no telnet-server
time daylight-time-rule western-europe
no web-management
web-management ssl
ip default-gateway 10.x.0.x
ip dns server-address priority 1 10.x.0.x
ip dns server-address priority 2 10.x.0.x
no ip ssh cipher aes128-cbc
no ip ssh cipher 3des-cbc
no ip ssh cipher aes192-cbc
no ip ssh cipher aes256-cbc
no ip ssh mac hmac-md5
no ip ssh mac hmac-sha1-96
no ip ssh mac hmac-md5-96
ip route 10.x.8.0 255.255.255.0 10.x.8.1
ip routing
snmp-server community "public" unrestricted
tls application web-ssl lowest-version tls1.2
tls application openflow lowest-version tls1.2
tls application syslog lowest-version tls1.2
tls application tr69 lowest-version tls1.2
aaa authentication ssh login public-key
oobm
ip address 10..x.x 255.255.255.0
exit
router rip
redistribute connected
exit
vlan 1
name "DEFAULT_VLAN"
no untagged 20-21
untagged 1-19,22-52
ip address 10.x.0.31 255.255.255.0
ip helper-address 10.x.0.17
ip igmp
exit
vlan 8
name "WiredUsers"
untagged 20
ip address 10.x.8.31 255.255.255.0
ip helper-address 10.x.0.17
ip igmp
exit
spanning-tree
```

Any suggestions as to why the DHCP offer cant hop from `10.x.8.31` to my machine on same subnet?

Comment: Can you capture and post the DHCP packets from the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this was that there was no proper route from the dhcp server to the vlan. It worked after I added a

sudo route add -net 10.36.8.0/24 gw 10.36.0.31 dev bond0 (where 10.36.0.31 is the address of the vlan) on the dhcp server. Thanks for taking the time to respond!

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.